# org-mode export to Latex — suppress generation of labels

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm using org-mode to write a report which I then export to LaTeX.
I have a few different `.org` files (one per chapter), which I export as "headless" LaTeX and then combine in a master `.tex` file.
This works nicely, except that the generated `.tex` files contain labels with conflicting numbers. So both `a.tex` and `b.tex` contain `\label{sec-1}`, for example.

As long as I never actually use these references then it's not much of a problem I think, although the warnings do annoy me. Is there any way to turn off the generation of these labels? It should be simple but I cannot find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: If you're using `GNU make`, you can just add the filtering to the rule of your main file. The syntax isn't hard, `sed` should be enough to do the job.

Comment: I'm not using `make`, but you gave me the idea to replace them within Emacs using an org-mode hook (see [separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18077000/98600)). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have written a bit of Lisp which will remove said labels after the export to LaTeX, which looks like this:

```lisp
(defun remove-orgmode-latex-labels ()
  "Remove labels generated by org-mode"
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
   (goto-char 1)
   (replace-regexp "\\\\label{sec-[0-9][^}]*}" "")
   )
)
(add-hook 'org-export-latex-final-hook 'remove-orgmode-latex-labels)
```

This seems to do the job without removing my own custom labels.

Comment: I wonder if the fundamental structure of Org export has changed in the last 7 years. `org-export-latex-final-hook` doesn't seem to be a thing anymore, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Why not writing your full report as one big Org file?

Anyway, if your prefer having multiple smaller files, I would advice "including" them in one Org master file, as this:

```
* Chapter 1

#+INCLUDE: "chapter1.org"

* Chapter 2

#+INCLUDE: "chapter2.org"
```

That way, Org sees only one file (then, I guess that your problem simply disappears), while you edit them as you wish.

Comment: Well I thought about this, but the major reason is that not all of the other files are really org files, some are pure LaTeX. Of course I could stick the LaTeX directly into the org file, but it's pretty hairy and I don't want to have to worry about the org-export messing it up somehow.

Comment: This is the approach I used.

Comment: IIRC, you can include LaTeX files as well (you have extra optional parameters to the INCLUDE keyword).

Answer (score 2):

As of now (18. 05. 2021) correct solution is this:

```
(defun my-latex-filter-removeOrgAutoLabels (text backend info)
  "Org-mode automatically generates labels for headings despite explicit use of `#+LABEL`. This filter forcibly removes all automatically generated org-labels in headings."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\label{sec:org[a-f0-9]+}\n" "" text)))

 (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions
              'my-latex-filter-removeOrgAutoLabels)
```

Only slight modification of previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me with recent (2020) Org-Mode:

```lisp
(defun rm-org-latex-labels (text backend _info)
  "Remove labels auto-generated by `org-mode' export to LaTeX."
  (when (eq backend 'latex)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\label{sec:org[a-f0-9]+}\n" "" text)))

(add-to-list #'org-export-filter-headline-functions
             #'rm-org-latex-labels)
```